# How to get ShingleFilterFactory to work with Hibernate Search?

Tags: hibernate, search, solr, lucene, hibernate-search

```
@AnalyzerDef(
        name = "tags",
        tokenizer = 
            @TokenizerDef(factory = PatternTokenizerFactory.class, 
                params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "pattern", value=",")
                }
            ),
        filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(
                factory = StopFilterFactory.class,
                params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "words", value = "data/ignorewords.txt"),
                    @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value = "true")
                }
            ),
            @TokenFilterDef(
                factory = SynonymFilterFactory.class,
                params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value="true"),
                    @Parameter(name = "expand", value="false"),
                    @Parameter(name = "synonyms", value="data/synonyms.txt")
                }
            ),
            @TokenFilterDef(
                factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class,
                params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "language", value="English")
                }
            ),
            @TokenFilterDef(
                factory = ShingleFilterFactory.class,
                params = { 
                    @Parameter(name = "minShingleSize", value="2"),
                    @Parameter(name = "maxShingleSize", value="3"),
                    @Parameter(name = "outputUnigrams", value="true"),
                    @Parameter(name = "outputUnigramsIfNoShingles", value="false")
                }
            ),
            @TokenFilterDef(
                factory = PositionFilterFactory.class,
                params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "positionIncrement", value = "100")
                }
            ),
            @TokenFilterDef(
                factory = PhoneticFilterFactory.class,
                params = { 
                    @Parameter(name = "encoder", value="RefinedSoundex"),
                    @Parameter(name = "inject", value="true")
                }
            )
        }
),
@AnalyzerDef(
    name = "querytime",
    tokenizer = 
        @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class,
            params = {
                @Parameter(name = "words", value = "data/ignorewords.txt"),
                @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value = "true")
            }
        ),
        @TokenFilterDef(
            factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class,
            params = { 
                @Parameter(name = "language", value="English")
            }
        ),
        @TokenFilterDef(
            factory = ShingleFilterFactory.class,
            params = { 
                @Parameter(name = "minShingleSize", value="2"),
                @Parameter(name = "maxShingleSize", value="3"),
                @Parameter(name = "outputUnigrams", value="true"),
                @Parameter(name = "outputUnigramsIfNoShingles", value="false")
            }
        ),
        @TokenFilterDef(
            factory = PositionFilterFactory.class,
            params = {
                @Parameter(name = "positionIncrement", value = "100")
            }
        ),
        @TokenFilterDef(
            factory = PhoneticFilterFactory.class,
            params = { 
                @Parameter(name = "encoder", value="RefinedSoundex"),
                @Parameter(name = "inject", value="true")
            }
        )
    }
)
})
```

Above is my Analyzer Definition where i am using **PatternTokenizerFactory** at index time to index phrase with multiple words.
And another one with **StandardTokenizerFactory** with **ShingleFilterFactory** to be used at querytime but however I am not able to receive the combinations of tokens from my search query.
What i was expecting was : when the search query is **My Search Query**, it should have been **my search** and **search query** but instead i am getting **my**, **search** and **query**

Below is my function

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
            Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
            // create native Lucene query
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = null;
            String[] fields = new String[] {"tags"}; 
            MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
                    Version.LUCENE_31, fields, fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer("querytime"));
            try {
                luceneQuery = parser.parse(searchQuery);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // wrap Lucene query in a org.hibernate.Query
            org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CityArea.class);

            // execute search
            List result = hibQuery.list();

            tx.commit();
            session.close();
            return result;
```

The problem is my index token are for ex: say **Word A**, **Word B** and i am search for **where is word a** (so that it will display record of **Word A**) but no result. This is because i don't want to display any result until the search query contains the phrase that is indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer from anybody lead myself to dig into the problem and found the answer myself. Since it may help others, i am writing it here and the solutions is pretty simple, just need to wrap the searchQuery into quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

i used the:

```
@TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
```

in your Tags analyser, your code is working perfectly fine.

now i am wondering why did you use a diferent tokenizer one for query and other for store ?

Comment: I used PatternTokenizerFactory in the store (index) time because my tags were comma separated, for ex: if the tags were => word A, word B, word C etc, i want to index word A, word B, word C instead of word, A, B, C which the StandardTokenizerFactory would do ie tokenize with space or special character. But the user search query string would be a string so i wanted to use ShingleFilterFactory to get multi word token to be able to search exactly with the indexed token.